# Externalize swagger message to properties file

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I'm having Apache-CXF REST service and using swagger for documentation. Default value for API changes based on environment (dev/qa/prod). I want to externalize the default value (in this case -5247710000779009) to a properties file which i'm already maintaining based on env for different purposes.

```
@ApiParam(value = "Customer information will be fetched by this account number", required = true, defaultValue = "5247710000779009")
```

How can i achieve this ?